# how to ping all local IP of a router(192.168.1.1) by using static IP (10...) in Ethernet connection

Tags: java, terminal

I want to find all local IP of a wifi router (192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255) by using static IP (that is given by ISP) in Ethernet connection.I need terminal command for that.
my laptop connected to the wifi router connection ,if I put arp -a then that will display all the IP address in the segment of 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255
Same thing I need with Ethernet connection .I want ping that local IP of router using static IP

Comment: The connection doesn't matter - wifi or ethernet; `arp -a` will give you the same information. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do with this information? **What is the problem you are trying to solve?** The ISP cannot give you a static IP in the 192.168.x.x range. This range is [designed for private use only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces).

Comment: Yes .I want to know all device's IP which is connected to the wifi by using static IP (10.x.x.x)

Comment: Your router has both wifi and ethernet connections. Some devices are connected to ethernet, and others to wifi - you want to know which devices are connected to which interface - is that the question?

Comment: If I am in outside my home ,I know main IP of my router(10.x.x.x).how can I know all device's IP and Mac addresses of then by using Mac terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in {1..255}
do
   ping -c 1 192.168.1.$I
done
```

... which literally pings all IPs from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255.

But you are probably going to get more useful results faster if you use `nmap`.  Read this article for a tutorial on using nmap for probing your local network:

- ["Who and What Is On My Network? Probing Your Network with Linux"](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/470979-who-and-what-is-on-my-network-probing-your-network-with-linux)

Comment: can you share the above code for windows command prompt or cygwin?

Comment: becaz if i put ping -c in cygwin then it is throwing some error.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am in outside my home ,I know main IP of my router(10.x.x.x).how
>   can I know all device's IP and Mac addresses of then by using Mac
>   terminal.

You cannot.

The IP address `10.x.x.x` is [reserved for private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) and is not routable over the Internet.

If you are sitting in a cafe and you try to ping `10.x.x.x`, it will not work; because this is not the public address of your Internet router.

Once you are home and you are connected to your router - go to `www.whatismyip.com` and you will see your *public IP address* which is the one that is assigned **to your router** directly from your ISP. Your router then shares this one public IP address with multiple devices *without each of them requiring their own public IP address*.

Once you are not longer connected to your home router (for example, you are connected directly from your mobile to the Internet) the only address that is reachable is the public one that your ISP assigns. From this address you can reach your router ... but you cannot go any further.

You can try to browse the management page for your router (http://your-public-ip) and then login to see what other devices are connected; but again, you will not be able to reach them from the Internet (unless you do something silly like allow all ports to be open from your router - do not do this).

Comment: Is there any other ways to achieve that concept.if it is public IP ,is possible ?